# How to trigger a task in Airflow when it's parent task fails, but skip it when it's in upstream_failed?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

As I can see there is no **Trigger Rule** what can differentiate `failed` and `upstream_failed` statuses. We have to behave differently when the parent has run but failed and when it has not run at all.

When the status of the parent task is:

- sucecess -> run the child task
- failed -> run the child task
- upstream_failed -> skip the child task
- skipped -> skip the child task

How can we get this behaviour?
Is it possible to write custom trigger rule for this?

I'm mostly interested in answer for Airflow 1.x

Comment: Would the `all_done` trigger rule work for you?

Comment: I think `ALL_DONE` trigger rule does not skip in any case. On both `fail` or `upstream_fail` the downstream task gets executed.